# SolrNet Multicore with AutoFac

Tags: solr, autofac, solrnet

I'm working on SolrNet 4.0. There are multicore implementation in Solr. I'm using Autofac as IoC.

```
var cores = new SolrServers
{
    new SolrServerElement 
    {
        Id = "entity1",
        DocumentType = typeof(Entity1).AssemblyQualifiedName,
        Url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/coreEntity1",
    },

    new SolrServerElement 
    {
        Id = "entity2",
        DocumentType = typeof(Entity2).AssemblyQualifiedName,
        Url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/coreEntity2",
    },
};


builder.RegisterModule(new SolrNetModule(cores));
var container = builder.Build();
var solrOperations1 =
    container.ResolveNamed<ISolrOperations<Entity1>>("entity1");
var solrOperations2 =
    container.ResolveNamed<ISolrOperations<Entity2>>("entity2");
```

above is registration of cores into IoC. 
But when I resolve from that container, got an error like below.

> The requested service 'entity1 (SolrNet.ISolrOperations`1[[Entity1,
>   TestApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]])' has
>   not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a
>   component to provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

Am I doing wrong or missing something in code?

Thanks.

Comment: This is your exact code? Because basically it is the same as the `ResolveSolrOperations_viaNamedWithMultiCore` https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/AutofacContrib.SolrNet.Tests/AutofacMulticoreFixture.cs#L107 unit test so it should just work...

Comment: yes. this is exact code. but not working on my side.

Comment: What happens inside SolrNetModule?

Comment: @TravisIllig the source is on github: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/AutofacContrib.SolrNet/SolrNetModule.cs

Comment: Deleted my answer from earlier; tested stuff out and I was incorrect.

Comment: I was going to try to repro the issue but it doesn't seem the NuGet packages for SolrNet are the same version of things that work with the source for the Autofac integration library there. For example, the Autofac module references `DefaultResponseParser<>` which isn't in the NuGet version. I tried really simple possibly not apples-to-apples repro and can't get the message to come up, so I'm guessing there's possibly something else going on.

Comment: I think SolrNetModule is not register properly. Am I right?